# Get the next 4 months in a formatted string

Tags: c#

What is the most elegant way of getting the following:

Starting from today's date, return an enumerable that would be the following:

July 1st
July 15th
August 1st
August 15th
September 1st
September 15th
October 1st
October 15th

Should account for things like if it's the end of the year, then it goes
December 15
January 1st.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your title asked for a string, but the question text asked for an enumerable.  Which is it?

Anyway, here's the enumerable:

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> GetPaymentDates()
{
   DateTime first = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1);
   DateTime fifteenth = first.AddDays(14);

   for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
   {
      yield return first;
      yield return fifteenth;

      first = first.AddMonths(1);
      fifteenth = first.AddDays(14);
   }
}
```

or a version that returns the strings:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetPaymentDates()
{
   DateTime current = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1);

   for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
   {
      yield return current.ToString("MMMM 1st");
      yield return current.ToString("MMMM 15th");

      current = current.AddMonths(1);
   }
}
```